# ReactJS component: fadeIn / fadeOut on mouse-enter / mouse-leave

Tags: javascript, css, events, reactjs

I've created a simple component on `reactjs` (kind of a value-picker: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/73ViVQxyfbEYCve7gDTJ?p=preview))

Now, I want the upper and lower parts of the control to be hidden (`opacity=0`) and animate to `opacity=1` when user hovers the central `div` (`.range-picker-selection`) with mouse.

Since there's no way I can operate with `DOM` directly from functions of my component (`reactjs` discourages this) I guess I should change the state ( to something like `state.expanded = true`) and rely on `reactjs` to reflect the change.

But how can I achieve the animation effect?
With jQuery I would have used `element.animate({opacity:0})` but now I don't have access to `DOM`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/5tLWNTtpsSWBUCgnKwQO?p=preview

I updated the state to have a hovered attribute and two mouse enter / leave methods to set the value which are bound the .range-picker-selection element in the render function

```
<div className="range-picker-selection" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}>

  onMouseEnterHandler: function () {
    this.setState({
      hovered: true
    })
  },
  onMouseLeaveHandler: function () {
    this.setState({
      hovered: false
    })  
  },
```

I also updated the render function to set the opacity to 0 or 1 accordingly for the elements.

`style={{opacity: this.state.hovered ? 1 : 0}}`

Finally, the actual animation is done with CSS animations

`transition: opacity 1s;`

I hope this helps

Comment: This works, but you could do it much simpler with just some CSS :-)

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea!)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand could you please show how exactly?

Comment: @ArturUdod, `.range-picker-selection:hover ~ .top-number,.range-picker-selection:hover ~ .bottom-number {opacity: 1}`.  Replace .top-number and .bottom-number with your top and bottom classes.  Look up the "sibling selector" for more info.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the sibling selector won't work for this example. `a~b` selects all `b` that come directly after `a`. There's no way in CSS to select the `a` that comes directly before b. The `.range-picker-selection:hover ~ .top-number` part will work, as `.top-number` is directly after `.range-picker-selection` in the DOM, but `.range-picker-selection:hover ~ .bottom-number` won't work as the `.bottom-number` element comes before `.range-picker-selection` in the DOM, not after like previously.

Comment: besides, in my scenario, I want to hide `div`-s with arrow icons as well. But anyway thanks for the answer @FakeRainBrigand, and @user3508122 too =)

Comment: Why not use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html